# How to count occurrences of string values in a range of cells, applying fractional weights when a cell has a list of values instead of just one value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Here is my input:
[image]

Here is the desired output:
[image]

Right now I'm calculating weights for each cell and use them in a two-stage process. For example, if a cell has a list of two values, I apply the weight of 0.5 and use SUMIF to calculate the final score. Here is my table of weights I have made using COUNTA and SPLIT:
[image]

I would like to eliminate this intermediary step if possible. Here is the spreadsheet you can see my test data in: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bhCDKeK8nlkIQpUaGJXMJ3j4T0iYeF6O_EJd0QI8apg/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've got a typo in your `sumif` formulas in your 'total weight' column, and that you meant to refer to F2 to F7 rather than B2 to B7 (otherwise you're not referring to the unique list of values you created, and I can't understand what you're trying to achieve). On the assumption I'm right, you can use the following to create the desired output in one go:

```
=arrayformula(let(combos,tocol(A2:D5),
splitcombos,split(combos," |",1,1),
weightpercombo,byrow(splitcombos,lambda(each,if(len(each),1/counta(each),))),
rawtbl,{tocol(splitcombos,1),tocol(weightpercombo,1)},
query(rawtbl,"select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1 label Col1 'Value', sum(Col2) 'Total weight'",0)))
```

EDIT

To produce single cell results in G2:G7 depending on the adjacent value in F2:F7, use the following in G2 and drag-copy down the column:

```
=arrayformula(let(
combos,tocol($A$2:$D$5),
splitcombos,split(combos," |",1,1),
weightpercombo,byrow(splitcombos,lambda(each,if(len(each),1/counta(each),))),rawtbl,{tocol(splitcombos,1),tocol(weightpercombo,1)},
query(rawtbl,"select sum(Col2) where Col1='"&F2&"' group by Col1 label sum(Col2) ''",0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for picking up the typo, your assumption is right.

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick.
Will I be able to somehow convert this into a cell formula, because the output I want is not quite a single table (but finding the values based on the adjacent column in a few different places)?

Comment: Try the second formula in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
=SORT(
  LET(c,A2:D5,
      v,UNIQUE(TOCOL(TRIM(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("|",1,c),"|")))),
     {v,SUMIF(c,"*"&v&"*",A9:D12)}))
```